# Adding Workflow to custom portlets (created by Plugins-SDK)

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay.

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

I want to add workflow (Kaleo) to a portlet which contains two textfields and a button.

The portlet is created through Plugins-SDK.

I've already gone through this blog: [How to add workflow capabilities on Knowledge Base articles or any custom assets in plugins](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/5786756)

But I just cant get so much information for my need.

Help  me.

Comment: You have a friend who has the exact same requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13837767/468763, but no answer

Comment: Do we add a workflow ___to a portlet___ or ___to an asset/entity___ within a portlet? If you can answer this question we can go ahead and I will also learn a thing or two in the process.

Comment: @PrakashK..The above link shows ,how they implement workflow in knowledge base article ,but how we can implement the same in our portlet?

Comment: @PrakashK..I think this is very important to us.

Comment: u can try this soluntion http://www.cignex.com/articles/applying-advanced-workflow-custom-assets-liferay-6

Comment: @LuckyBoy..This solution is just same as the above link(in my question) content.

Comment: sry i am little bit busy...give me ur email id will forward the code to you.....

Comment: @Sree ur problem solved?

Comment: @LuckyBoy..sory..i hav some other issues right now..wil reply u tommorow..after trying..ok..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following it may help you

http://www.cignex.com/articles/applying-advanced-workflow-custom-assets-liferay-6

http://liferayzone.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/kaleo-workflow-configuration-for-custom-portlet-in-liferay-6-1/

Download workflow bundle and follow the steps which i specified in the document.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/LiferayWorkFlowPortlet